# Wpf Image control (bound to property) not refreshing after the first time

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding

The control shows only the first image , if the property changes ( and event is fired ) the control doesn't even try to get the value again.
If when the window initializes the property is null then nothing is displayed also if the image is valorized later.
The image is about 2MB bitmap

This is the XAML

```xml
<Image
    Grid.Row="1" 
    Grid.Column="0" 
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"    
    Source="{Binding Path=CurrentImg,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode= TwoWay}"/>
```

This is in the view model:

```
private BitmapImage _CurrentImg;

public BitmapImage CurrentImg
{
    get { return _CurrentImg; }
    set
    {
        _CurrentImg = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentImg");
    }
}

public void ButtonCommandExecute()
{
    TestAlgo.Next();

    this.CurrentImg = TestAlgo.toWpfBitmapImage();  
}
```

Finally this is the method that creates the BitmapImage from System.Drawing.Bitmap

```
 public BitmapImage toWpfBitmapImage()
    { return convertBitmapToBitmapSource(this.CurBitmap); }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a <see cref="System.Drawing.Bitmap"/> to <see cref="System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bitmap">Source</param>
    /// <returns>Converted image</returns>
    public static BitmapImage convertBitmapToBitmapSource(System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap)
    {


        //salvo la bitmap nel MemoryStream, in modo che lo posso usare come sorgente per una nuova BitmapSource
        BitmapImage imageToReturn = new BitmapImage();
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {


            bitmap.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
            //creo la nuova BitmapSource da ritornare
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            imageToReturn.BeginInit();
            imageToReturn.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            imageToReturn.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat;
            imageToReturn.StreamSource = stream;
            imageToReturn.EndInit();
        }
        return imageToReturn;

    }
```

This is where main window is instantiated, the view model is passed as a parameter and is set inside the constructor.

```
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        MainWindowVM MainWinVM;
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);
            MainWinVM = new MainWindowVM();
            MainWindow win = new MainWindow(MainWinVM);
            win.Show();
        }
        protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWinVM.SaveDb();
            base.OnExit(e);
        }
    }


     public partial class MainWindow : Window
     {
       public MainWindow()
       {
          this.DataContext = new MainWindowVM();
          InitializeComponent();

       }
       public MainWindow(MainWindowVM vm)
       {
          DataContext = vm;
          InitializeComponent();

       }
     }
```

Comment: So `ButtonCommandExecute` executes fine but image does not change? How does `CurrentImg` property look like?

Comment: Exactly, i updated the code.
The value of the property changed the event is rose but the get{} is never called. 
The get method gets called only one time when window's dataContext is set and then never again.

Comment: Is `ButtonCommandExecute` executed asynchronously by any chance or all this happens on UI thread?

Comment: No, all in the main thread.

Comment: Post datacontext and notify property changed.  Sounds like notify is not working properly.

Comment: For the RaisePropertyChanged the vie model ineherit from MvvmFoundation.Wpf.ObservableObject.
Datacontext is set in the App.xaml.cs.
Btw i don't think that the problem is there because there are other bound controls other than Image that work just fine.

Comment: Should not break it but why do you have UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay on an image?

Comment: Just trying different things.
Earlier it was just {Binding CurrentImg}

Comment: @N4rk0 Did you ever resolve this?  I have the same issue and haven't been able to figure out why the get; is not called after the PropertyChange notification.

Comment: @N4rk0 I just found my answer:  I neglected to subclass INotifyPropertyChanged in the VM class.  I'd added the code but not done the subclass. DOH!

Answer (score 1):

Have you implemented INotifyPropertyChanged Interface???

Please use sendPropertyChanged("CurrentImg ") on setter of CurrentImg after setting value.

```
    private BitmapImage  currentImg;

    public BitmapImage  CurrentImg
    {
        get { return currentImg; }
        set 
        { 
            currentImg = value;
            SendPropertyChanged("CurrentImg");
        }
    }
```

Please refer following link.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes i have 
private BitmapImage _CurrentImg;
        public BitmapImage CurrentImg
        {
            get { return _CurrentImg; }
            set
            {
                _CurrentImg = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentImg");
            }
        }